# Git: Branch for testing with persistent config file

Tags: git, merge, branch

The setup:
I have two branches: master and testing. I add new features on the testing branch and then merge them to the master branch. However, in a recent web project, I have a git repository on my server and my local machine, so everytime I merge onto master and push to orign, I can pull the new files on my server. The problem is that I use a different configuration file (for the MySQL database) on my local environment than on my server. So ideally I want to have a two branches: One with the production ready config and one with a testing config where I can also add new features. How can I accomplish this?

TL;DR 
How can I merge two branches without losing the configuration file of one of them?

Comment: Files that depend on the server such as config file should not be tracked by git. However data like that can be stored in the server environment (environment variables)...

Comment: Ok, so I would only create a template config file. But is there actually a way in git to have a persistent file (or commit) even if you try to merge branches?